# Is it possible to have the "@xxx" in the comments automatically updated when a user's username has changed?

Tags: feature-request, comments, notifications

Many times, I have come across Stack Overflow questions with long comment threads. In some cases, a user changed their display name, so a lot of the time I have no idea who's responding to who.

Is it possible for the Stack Overflow Team to implement some kind of feature to resolve this issue?

Comment: I actually find it useful in cases where a user attempts to masquerade as someone else, or even just do something like anglicize a name since they *"think"* that will get them better responses. Most of the time I don't really see an issue unless someone suddenly want's to change their *"handle"* to something different whilst in the middle of a comment chain. The current account name is always shown on the comment anyway. Not to mention [*"Comments are not important"*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240839/252977) in case you did not already know.

Comment: Cross-site counterpart, [status-declined]: [*Change all @username references in comments when a user changes their name?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/31851/242059).

Comment: If comments no longer make sense - just flag them all as obsolete...

Comment: Also to weigh in on *"Many times, I have come across SO questions with long comment threads..."* - My personal tip would be that if there is a really long comment chain already, then the question is probably best left alone. Either flag any comments that appear resolved to be removed and come back later, or just walk away. If someone does not "get it" right away, then no amount of convincing really seems to matter. So it's the "long comment chain" itself that is more of a problem than how the names appear of the people participating within them

Comment: @NeilLunn I think it is bad advice, I have learned lot of things just reading long comment chain.

Comment: @IamtheMostStupidPerson What you are missing here is that "learning something" should not be happening from the comments. The content belongs in the question or the answer. Which is basically what is being prompted here. To much conversation back and forth clarifies neither. Almost to the point where I'm considering scrapping the comments here and just posting all that content as an answer. Since that would be where it **should** belong.

Comment: @NeilLunn Yes, I can understand what you said. But even we find a mistake in code or very similar one and then we edit it(not mine, others answers) that edit is usually rejected saying "This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer." or similar one. That's why most questions includes very useful comments